# CMake: Avoiding inclusion of Windows SDK from CMakeLists.txt. Using MinGW instead msvc

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw

I have a project that **compiles right** when I configure it **from the command line**:

```
cmake ..  -DCMAKE_GENERATOR="MinGW Makefiles"
generator is set to MinGW Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/jose/Documents/ApD_PRG/test_v2/Build
```

But surprisingly **it doesn't when I asjust** it at the beginning of the **CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set (CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
message("generator is set to ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")

set(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME "testProject")
...
```

---

```
$ cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
generator is set to MinGW Makefiles
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18363.   <--------- HERE!!!
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/jose/Documents/ApD_PRG/test_v2/Build
```

***It automatic gets the Windows SDK, and the project doesn't compile any more.***

Please, somebody so kind to help me in the avoid of the Windows SDK inclusion from CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks in advance

**pd: I need this way, because I want that eclipse automatic select the right compiler on import**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you simply cannot set the generator from within the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html) (emphasis mine)

> **The value of this variable should never be modified by project code.** A generator may be selected via the cmake(1) -G option, interactively in cmake-gui(1), or via the CMAKE_GENERATOR environment variable.

Since I'm not familiar with Eclipse I cannot guarantee that it works, but you can try to set the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` env-variable to `MinGW Makefiles` when using CMake 3.15 or later.

However, there is a good chance that

- the CMake plugin you're using needs to be aware of the generator being used in order to be able to parse the build output, and as such manually adds `-G <generator>` for the generator configured in the plugin to the CMake invocation, thus overriding the value set in the env-variable, or
- the Eclipse plugin only knows how to handle the output of the default generator, but also doesn't enforce it with `-G <generator>`, in which case you setting a different generator might cause it to fail to parse the build output for errors / warnings.